# Can't connect to MongoDB with correct credentials with Grails App

Tags: grails, jelastic, gorm-mongodb

In my config.groovy file I am connecting to MongoDB like so

```
    environments {
       production {
//        db.configuration.file=System.getProperty("user.home") + "/mydb.cfg"
        grails.mongo.host = "Snip Snip"    //dataSourcesConfig.get 'host'
        grails.mongo.databaseName = 'edupal'      //dataSourcesConfig.get 'dbname'
        grails.mongo.username = 'admin'       //dataSourcesConfig.get 'user'
        grails.mongo.password = 'V********k'      //dataSourcesConfig.get 'password'
    }
    development {
        grails.mongo.databaseName = 'edupal'
    }
}
```

when I deploy my .war file the page appears blank because I am getting this error in my TOMCAT log. I am 110% certain the password and username that I use are correct. When I 
go to RockMongo and login, I copy and paste. I can run the app perfectly off my local machine.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'mongoTransactionManager' while setting constructor
>   argument with key [1]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property
>   'datastore'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception
>   on object creation; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException:
>   Failed to authenticate to database [edupal], username = [admin],
>   password = [V********k]   ... 5 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property
>   'datastore'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception
>   on object creation; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException:
>   Failed to authenticate to database [edupal], username = [admin],
>   password = [V********k]   ... 5 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': FactoryBean threw exception
>   on object creation; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException:
>   Failed to authenticate to database [edupal], username = [admin],
>   password = [V********k]   ... 5 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException:
>   Failed to authenticate to database [edupal], username = [admin],
>   password = [V********k]   at
>   org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore.initializeIndices(MongoDatastore.java:285)
>     at
>   org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore.createMongoTemplate(MongoDatastore.java:276)
>     at
>   org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.MongoDatastore.afterPropertiesSet(MongoDatastore.java:221)
>     at
>   org.grails.datastore.gorm.mongo.bean.factory.MongoDatastoreFactoryBean.getObject(MongoDatastoreFactoryBean.groovy:54)
>     ... 5 more

Comment: Have you tried logging in with the same credentials using the `mongo` shell on the server where you deployed your app to? It sounds like you might be logging in via Rockmongo on your local machine, which may not be testing the same connectivity. You want to ensure there isn't a firewall blocking access from the environment your production Grails app is deployed in to your production MongoDB instance.

Comment: Which IP address did you sets in your preferences? Also, I recommend to ask your hosting provider for help with this issue.